# Imputar dados no dataframe baseado na verificação de strings de uma lista se estão contidas em na coluna X

Tags: python, string, loop, dataframe, concatenação-de-string

Eu estou tentando fazer uma espécie de OHE mas preciso verificar a string contida, isso porque a coluna que diz a área do conhecimento do usuário não possui apenas um item de string, pode conter todos os itens disponíveis. Por exemplo:

| user | conhecimento |
| --- | --- |
| 659874 | Saúde, Agropecuária |
| 655478 | Educação |
| 478878 | Filosofia, Línguas, Educação |
| 254786 | Esportes |

Eu possuo uma lista de conhecimentos únicos:

**list_conhecimento** = [Saúde, Agropecuária, Edução, Filosofia, Esportes, Línguas]

Estou fazendo um laço para adicionar manualmente uma coluna nova para cada item da lista:

```
for item in list_conhecimento:
    col_name = "conhecimento_" + str(item)
    df[col_name] = 0
```

Depois que as colunas forem criadas, eu quero percorrer a coluna conhecimento e verificar se aquele item da lista está contido no item da coluna conhecimento, se sim, então adiciona 1 na coluna respectiva que foi criada para aquela área. Por exemplo:

| user | conhecimento | conhecimento_Saúde | conhecimento_Agropecuária | conhecimento_ Educação | conhecimento_Filosofia | conhecimento_Esportes | conhecimento_Línguas |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 659874 | Saúde, Agropecuária | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 655478 | Educação | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 478878 | Filosofia, Línguas, Educação | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 254786 | Esportes | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

Eu estou tentando fazer assim, não ele não faz a imputação do 1, e ainda cria uma coluna duplicada de conhecimento ao final do dataframe.

```
def imputar_numero(df, list_conhecimento):
  df['conhecimento'] = df['conhecimento'].str.split(',')
  for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for item in row['conhecimento']:
        for conhecimento in list_conhecimento:
            if item.strip() == conhecimento:
                df.loc[index, "conhecimento" + str(conhecimento)] = 1
df.drop(columns=['conhecimento'])
return df
```

Como eu posso fazer isso?

Answer (score -1):

Uma maneira de fazer isso seria usando o método `str.get_dummies()` do pandas. Isso criaria colunas binárias para cada item na lista de conhecimentos únicos e faria a imputação automática de 1 ou 0 dependendo da presença ou ausência do item na coluna original 'conhecimento'.

```
df = df.join(df['conhecimento'].str.get_dummies(', '))
```

Além disso, você pode adicionar prefixo para as colunas criadas, utilizando o `add_prefix`.

Veja um exemplo com a sua tabela:

```
import pandas as pd

# cria o dataframe com a coluna 'conhecimento'
df = pd.DataFrame({'user': [659874, 655478, 478878, 254786], 
                   'conhecimento': ['Saúde, Agropecuária', 'Educação', 'Filosofia, Línguas, Educação', 'Esportes']})

# cria colunas binárias e imputa valores 1 ou 0
df = df.join(df['conhecimento'].str.get_dummies(', ').add_prefix('conhecimento_'))


print(df)
```